# How to know all messages that one object can response?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

can I get the list of messages that one object can response in runtime? (in Cocoa).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Wooble's answer is correct.  An object can choose to respond to a message or not, and you can even add/remove/swap methods at runtime.

If you want to get a list of methods that an object currently implements (note: this is different than what messages an object will respond to), you can do so like this:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

Class class = [MyClass class];
unsigned int numMethods = 0;
Method * methods = class_copyMethodList(class, &numMethods);
for (int i = 0; i < numMethods; ++i) {
  SEL methodSelector = method_getName(methods[i]);
  NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(methodSelector));
}
free(methods);
```

This is pretty neat, but be aware that this will only give you the instance methods *implemented* by the class.  In other words, it will *not* give you the methods inherited from a superclass.  To get those methods, you must inspect the superclass directly.

If you want to get all of the *class* methods implemented by a specific class, then you replace:

```
Class class = [MyClass class]:
```

with:

```
Class class = objc_getMetaClass(class_getName([MyClass class]));
```

Comment: Dear Dave: Thanks a lot, it really help, and I'd keep it in my notes.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible. Objective C supports dynamic method resolution; an object could respond to literally any message sent to it.

Comment: For example, I once saw a class that transformed Roman numeral messages into the corresponding integers.

Comment: Then how runtime know the object can ( or NOT) response the message? It just send the message and wait for exception?

Comment: NSObject has much built-in functionality for this: see the docs for respondsToSelector:, methodSignatureForSelector:, forwardInvocation:, doesNotRecognizeSelector: